# How to hide the tooltip in dimplejs?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclicklistener, dimple.js

I used  dimple._showPointTooltip to show my tooltip. In mouseout or mouseleave I want hidden it. Which command do I use to do this?

There are many components in this display.

Command used to display tooltip:

```
myChart.draw();
mySeries.shapes.on("click", function (e) {
    dimple._showPointTooltip(e, this, myChart, mySeries);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find a more suitable solution, I identified each object and removed them:

```
        series.shapes.on("mouseleave", function (e) {
            svg.select(".dimple-tooltip").remove();
            svg.select(".dimple-custom-tooltip-box").remove();
            svg.select(".dimple-custom-tooltip-label").remove();
            svg.select(".dimple-line-marker-circle").remove();
            svg.select(".dimple-custom-line-marker-circle").remove();
            svg.select(".dimple-tooltip-dropline").remove();
            svg.select(".dimple-custom-tooltip-dropline").remove();     
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the circles that have attached the event that shows up the tooltip with this way:

```
yourSvg.selectAll('circle').remove()
```